# Find last int (1-9) stored in long of bits (each int represented by 4 bits)

Tags: java, c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am working on a Tic-Tac-Toe AI, and want to find the last move (Opponents last move before current turn) using a long provided by the Game Engine.

Each space is represented by a single digit integer 1-9 (which i will subtract 1 from to get moves 0-8, plus 9 for off-board moves which are stored in the long as 0xF).

0xE is used to represent NULL, but will be treated by my program the same as an off-board move.

Here is how the game state is encoded:

```
Used to encode game State, first 4 bits are first move, second 4 bits second move, (4 * 9 = 36 bits) bits 33-36 are the last Move. Each move is the coordinate singleton + 1, therefore the tictactoe board is recorded as...
  1 |  2 | 3
  4 |  5 | 6
  7 |  8 | 9

Normal equation for singleton is row*3+col, but you cannot record a state as 0, therefore game state moves are row*3+col + 1, note difference Coordinate singleton is 0..8, board game state position is 1..9;
 1 | 2 | 3
 4 | 5 | 6
 7 | 8 | 9



The game state 0x159, X first move 9; O move 2 is 5;move 3 X is 1


 X _ _ 
 _ O _
 _ _ 9



 Sets off board set all 4 bits (aka 0xf).


e.g., 0x12f45, On X's second move (game move 3)
 X picked a Coordinate outside the tictactoe range.


Duplicate guesses onto occupied square are just saved


e.g., 0x121 implies X has used position 1 on both his
 first and second move


Null coordinate usually caused by exception is saved as 0xE


e.g., 0x1E3; implies on game move 2, O first move, O throw an exception
 most likely causes index array out of bounds
```

As of now, here is how I am finding the last move using the engine's game state:

```
private int LastMoveFinder(final Board brd, int move)
{
    char prevMove = Long.toHexString(brd.getGameState()).charAt(0);

    if(prevMove == 'f' || prevMove == 'e')
        return 9;
    else
        return Character.getNumericValue(prevMove) - 1;
}
```

But, I am sure there is a faster way (performance wise) to find the last move using some sort of bitshift method, as our AI's will be tested against each other for speed (nanoSec/move) and win-tie-loss ratio.

I have read up on bitshifting and searched all over stackoverflow for answers to questions like mine, but nothing I have tried to implement into my program has worked.

I am sure i'm missing something simple, but have not taken a course that covers bitshifting and masking yet, so I am at somewhat of a loss.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is this marked with both java and c++? which one do you want?

Comment: The most performance efficient method is to drop the bit twiddling and use regular sized integers.  There is no bonus on modern platforms for conserving memory.  I'm fairly certain that the platforms running your program will have enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can get 4 bits of a `int` by AND'ing it with the bitmask `0xf` shifted left by 4 * `moveNumber` bits. Then, shift the result right by 4 * `moveNumber` bits to get an int, and apply your move logic to that int. The modified method is:

```
/**
   Assumes moveNumber is 0 indexed.
 */
private int LastMoveFinder(final Board brd, int moveNumber)
{
    int moveMask = 0xf << (4 * moveNumber);
    int prevMove = (brd.getGameState() & moveMask) >>> (4 * moveNumber);

    if (prevMove == 0xf || prevMove == 0xe) {
        return 9;
    } else {
        return prevMove - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I implemented the code, but its not quite working.  As of now, the method finds the move the first time it searches, but all subsequent runs for the game return -1 (prevMode - 1, so really prevMode is returning 0).  I ran with move starting at 1 and 0, and the results are the same.

Comment: EDIT: WORKING.  The move number was off by one because the current move is always 1 more than the number of moves when the game state is encoded.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Using the bitmask and bitshift to find the last move  vs. converting to a HexString is about 4 times faster (.446ms vs 2.22ms)

Comment: After further testing, the method works perfectly UNLESS a bad move is made.  The (prevMove == 0xf || prevMove 0xe) condition is never triggered.